# Last element of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

```
<span ng-repeat="sla in terminals">
    {{sla}},
</span>
```

Is there a way to not generate the komma on the last element of the repeat?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes it is:

```
 {{sla}}{{ ($last ) ? '' : ','}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without ng-repeat:

```
{{ terminals.join(',') }}
```